# Парная выборка или счет

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте! У меня появился вопрос насчет сортировки. Допустим у меня есть таблица в базе данных MySQL.

```
|id|idone   |idtwo  |  
| 1|.......2|......1|  
| 2|.......1|......2|  
| 3|.......3|......1|  
| 4|.......2|......3|  
| 5|.......4|......6|  
| 6|.......5|......1|  
| 7|.......6|......4|  
| 8|.......1|......5|
```

в базе есть много таких записей...где `idone` и idtwo могут быть разными.
и мне нужно выбрать все записи где `idone` первой записи равен `idtwo` второй записи. Получается что нужно отыскать пару. и должно получиться что то вроде такого

```
|id|idone   |idtwo  |  
| 1|.......2|......1|  
| 2|.......1|......2|     
| 5|.......4|......6|  
| 7|.......6|......4|  
| 6|.......5|......1|  
| 8|.......1|......5|
```

таким образом у нас получилось 3 пары...такие пары я знаю как выбрать, ну а вот как потом их найти. если что то плохо объяснил - спрашивайте, просто сложно объяснить суть проблемы.

Comment: не бойтесь описывать физический смысл для ваших данных. скажем, написать "у меня есть проводки Д50К51 и Д51К50, нужно посчитать количество таких корреспондеций" или "вася друг пети, надо выяснить петя друг васи или нет" и станет гораздо понятнее. легче воспринимать задачу не на абстрактных данных, пытаясь подобрать смысл под ваши числа и понять что вы хотите потом в итоге получить, а помочь решить задачу, опираясь на предметную область.  
иногда можно модифицировать задачу и первоначальный вопрос может трансформироваться, решение будет и более правильным и более простым.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
t1.id, t1.idone, t1.idtwo, 
t2.id, t2.idone, t2.idtwo
FROM
testtable AS t1
JOIN testtable AS t2 ON t1.idone = t2.idtwo
```

Надеюсь, я правильно понял задачу, и нужны пары записей, где idone первой равен idtwo второй. Дважды смотрим на исходную таблицу, как будто это две разных: t1 и t2.

С вашими данными это возвращает такие пары:

```
id  idone   idtwo   id  idone   idtwo
1   2   1   2   1   2
2   1   2   1   2   1
2   1   2   3   3   1
2   1   2   6   5   1
3   3   1   4   2   3
4   2   3   2   1   2
5   4   6   7   6   4
6   5   1   8   1   5
7   6   4   5   4   6
8   1   5   1   2   1
8   1   5   3   3   1
8   1   5   6   5   1
```

Как и писали:

> выбрать все записи где idone первой
> записи равен idtwo второй записи

Comment: а вот это в принципе интересно...буду пробовать...спасибо всем за отзывы

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.idone,t1.idtwo from table t1 join table t2 on t1.idone=t2.idtwo and t1.idtwo=t2.idone where t1.idone<t1.idtwo;
```

Выведет **только** те id, у которых есть инверсная пара.

upd: Количество парных записей. Если одна запись имеет инверсную пару выведет 1.

```
select count(*) from table t1 join table t2 on t1.idone=t2.idtwo and t1.idtwo=t2.idone where t1.idone<t1.idtwo;
```

Comment: хм, у меня ведь одна таблица

Comment: @kazaца: слово "table" - ключевое в MySQL, если это имя таблицы, надо в обратные кавычки его: \`table\`

Comment: Вместо `table` нужно вставить название вашей таблицы. Я думаю, несложно догадаться. Добавил про количество.

Comment: эх ладно, никто меня не понимает буду сам разбираться...

Comment: Попытайтесь еще раз.

Answer (score 0):

Да слегка запутано.

```
WHERE idone={$idone} AND idtwo={$idtwo}
```

Так?

Comment: а зачем фигурные скобки? можно сказать, что выборку я делаю правильно, как показано во второй "таблице", но как потом посчитать эти пары. Вот это вот уже вопрос.

Comment: что значит посчитать пары?
что должно быть в результате?

Comment: в результате должно быть число пар строк, погляди на вторую таблицу. там я выбрал из всей таблицы пар...если посмотреть крест накрест...то можно увидеть зависимость между ними...получается что строк у меня 6, а пар 3...вот мне и нужно как то посчитать сколько пар...но не делением на 2

Comment: пускай будет создаваться массив с тремя элементами со значениями idtwo первой записи из пары